# I can't seem to make Visual Studio find my remappings

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, blockchain, smartcontracts, brownie

I'm currently studying smart contracts and chain-link tech (currently watching and learning from freecodecamp) and I have been stuck apparently at this stage, I've written the codes following the clip and also have replaced them with the ones the author wrote from GitHub to make sure I didn't mistype, but it seems I can't get my Fund_Me codes to import the @chainlink line even though I have my AggregatorV3 and SafeMath file ready and downloaded.

This is the Brownie-config.yaml codes:

```yaml
    dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

And this is the line with the problem:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some code.

Comment: This is the Brownie-config.yaml codes:

dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'


And this is the line with the problem:
mport "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

Comment: Is the title of your file `brownie-config.yaml` or `Brownie-config.yaml`. Also it looks like you had some spacing issues. And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I named it with a cap B, the error I'm getting is that on the import code lines, it says this
Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File import callback not supported